# How to convert .bin/.cue files into DVD-ROM UDF-ISO file in linux?

Tags: linux, iso, dvd, udf

How to convert `.bin`/`.cue` files into DVD-ROM UDF-ISO file in linux ? I found that `genisoimage` can make CD-ROM UDF with that command:

```
 genisoimage -udf -o MY_FILE.iso ~/MY_DIR/
```

but I didn't find for DVD-ROM. Is there a program to do it on linux ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You  need to install [bchunk](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bchunk) ( **BinChunker** ) .

To convert type the following command :

```
bchunk your_file.bin your_file.cue file.iso
```

Comment: Unfortunately it makes a CD-ROM type not DVD-ROM.

Comment: The type for both CD and DVD is ISO.